# Where is my wallet?

Tags: riddle

While sleeping some fiendish creature has absconded with my wallet! He left this note, and each clue gives me a letter. Can you help me figure out where my wallet went?

> 1. The middle of my brothers I thought I was a car, but maybe I'm just dead. Better use my tail.
> 2. You'll need the right portmanteau for this, don't get bewildered. Both sides work.
> 3. Some things start inside this, others put me inside them. Just don't use my duplicate.
> 4. Some people think that we are a _____, but I guess our names are confusing. We're really in a false group. I have two (or maybe one) of these, but you better use the first.
> 5. First in my group,  I am unlike the rest and I am fifth overall, twice.
> 6. Carl really likes these. Use my first duplicate.
> 7. To me you are you, but to yourself you are _____.
> 8. Well, I was worried I was wasting all this writing. Will you weep, or win?
>
> **Where is my wallet?**

Hint 1:

> 6 is a reference to a show.

Hint 2:

> The letters from the description are not in order to discourage deriving letters from final answer.

Hint 3:

> For 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6 the second part of the description refers to how to derive the letter.

Hint 4:

> For 4, think food.

Hint 5:

> For 1, don't think brothers in the literal sense, but rather take it as it is the middle of three things that have a strong relation to each other.

Provide the answer and letter for each description along with the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm putting the accepted answers in a separate place to collate our guesses as this is turning into something collaborative.

1.
**Added by OP:**

> Answer: **Wraith**, Letter: **h**. Rolls Royce has 3 car models named Ghost, Wraith and Phantom. The Wraith model is the middle priced version of this. In hindsight, this seemed a rather too difficult, but I really thought the "I thought I was a car" part of the description would eventually be taken more literally. Throwing in the descriptor "brothers", and assuming that people would correlate that relation with price/model tier was probably not correct thinking.

2.

> D from dumbfounded. (@Astralbee)

3.

> E from egg.

4.
**Added by OP**:

> Answer: **berry**, Letter: **e**;  Again, this one, in hindsight seemed a little too non-specific and probably not descriptive enough. I had hoped hints like "We're really in a false group" would help.  The intention was for someone to derive this answer considering specific fruits (e.g. strawberry, blackberry, raspberry) that have the name berry in it, but are actually considered accessory fruits or "false" fruits. The description for this one was probably too "out there" for the answer to be developed.

5.

> N as the fifth character from Boron.

6.

> L as the first duplicate in llama, from Carl Wheezer in Jimmy Neutron.

7.

> I (@NetJohn)

8.

> W from the alliteration (@NetJohn)

Overall:

> _DE_NLIW

Your wallet is in

> NEW DELHI!

Comment: Yes all of those submissions for the answers are correct - letter and answer. The final answer is also, correct. If nobody can get a correct answer for 1 or 4 I may add another hint or two.

Comment: I think now that the puzzle has been solved interest was lost in the last few clues. Ill accept this answer as it is correct.

Comment: @Colton Most setters try to give a solver some hints and some time to let them come up with the full solution themselves, though that doesn't seem to have helped here. Another option, so the answers aren't kept a mystery forever, is to annotate the final solution with (e.g.) "Added by OP" notes that fill in missing or incorrect details. Something to consider.

Comment: I’ll be honest, I’ve tried for a while on the last two answers and just couldn’t get anywhere with it, even with the extra hints. This one beat me!

Comment: I actually meant to put number 4 this weekend! I guessed the correct answer based on the letters remaining, the hint, and the fact that you could consider one of the letters to be either a vowel or a consonant. Thanks for the great puzzle! I would never have gotten 1 though.

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer:

5.

> Word is one, since it is first but fifth alphabetically (eight five four nine one seven six three two), and is the only one that is not a multiple of something.  So let's say it's the letter "o"

7.

> "I" should be self evident

8.

> Lot of little lousy letters laying in the line, so I'm guessing "w" based on the alliteration.

Overall:

> _ _ _ _ O _ I W
>
>  Since I can't find ANY words that end in IW, either it's a city name or I've messed up.  Most likely the latter.

Comment: Yes to 7 and 8, no to 5 and I never said that the letters were in order ;).

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer, and a guess:

1. The middle of my brothers I thought I was a car, but maybe I'm just dead. Better use my tail.

> Is it custom car designer Ed Roth? "Roth" is in the the middle of "my b**roth**ers", and he designed the Hot Rod. The "tail" of Ed is **D**.

2. You'll need the right portmanteau for this, don't get bewildered. Both sides work.

> Another word for bewildered is **dumbfounded**, which is a portmanteau of the words *dum*b and *founded*; also "both sides work" because it begins and ends with the same letter **D**.

And my guess at the final answer, based on these letters and the others you've confirmed so far is:

> **SWINDLED** - meaning "use deception to deprive (someone) of money or possessions".

Comment: Nice job on 2! I was worried no one would get that one! 1 is incorrect though and so is your final answer.

Comment: No a compound is a word made up of two words that has no blending.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, they put it as combining the first word with a different second (complete) word, which I assumed was correct.  I'll remove my above misinformed comments to shorten this thread.  Also, you can't hide text in comments...they prefer the use of rot13 instead.

Comment: Actually "qhzosbhaqrq" is a portmanteau of "qhzo" and "pbasbhaqrq."

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer:**

5.

> N for the fifth letter in Boron, the fifth element in the periodic table. It's the first in its group and the only one in its group which is a metal

**Edit 2:**

1.

> L? Marcel Renault was the middle Renault brother that started the Renault company in 1899, and died in 1903 aged 31.

6.

> L? Carl Sagan was famous for saying ['billions and billions'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Sagan#Sagan_units) so taking the first duplicate, 'L'.

Since the letter is correct but the answer is wrong, I can only think of

> L as the first duplicate in Llama, from the online series llamas with hats, where Carl and Paul have a series of crazy adventures.

Since this is the correct word but the wrong series, I will finally guess at

> L as the first duplicate in Llama, from Jimmy Neutron, in which Carl Wheezer loves llamas.

**Edit 3:**

Edited 5 to respond to @Colton.

**Edit 4:**

Edited 6, guess at 3.

3.

> E as the non-duplicate in egg. Some things start inside an egg, others use eggs e.g. some recipes.

Comment: The answer for 5 is correct, but the letter is wrong. The clue for which letter may have been a little too difficult or unclear, but take hint from the numbers already present in the description. Also, the reasoning for why it is unlike the rest is correct too. 1 is incorrect, how could a person confuse himself as a car? 6 you got the correct letter (funny coincidence), but the wrong answer. 6 is meant to be a pop culture reference, but may be a little too vague. If there's not enough answers on these I will add hints.

Comment: You got it now! I added a few hints to the description as well, may add more later if some of the descriptions continue to go without guesses.

Comment: I had another stab at 6 but I’m not sure if it’s correct.

Comment: You now have the right answer and letter...but the wrong show. If you end up getting the other answers I'll take this one because its so close and almost fits (Carl is a llama, but I guess he would like llamas).

Comment: OK, one final go at 6. And added my guess for 3, this is a great puzzle!

Comment: You got 6 now! Yep good job on 3 too, you're getting there.